# In Angular 6 I get the error "NullInjectorError: No provider for Store" in a component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, store, ngxs

This simplified component dispatches an action to save data to the store:

```
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { ViewLogin } from '../actions/login.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  onSignInClick(login: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(new ViewLogin({ login }));
  }
}
```

It always brings about the error `NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!`.

The weird thing is that I have the same code in another component in the app and it's working without any problem!

Any idea?

Comment: You need to make sure that `Store` is added into the providers array of your module. Make sure that the module is either the one that declares `NavbarComponent`, or a parent module such as `AppModule`

Comment: @user184994 Thank you! I did it before but forgot this part xD

Answer (score 4):

With NGXS you don't need to inject the `Store` directly as a provider, rather import the `NgxsModule` into the root `AppModule`.

Here from the documentation:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forRoot([
      ZooState
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I'm doing this and Store is not provided. No idea why.